# My wallpaper cannot be changed and my ubuntu tweak cannot launch even after an ugrade

Tags: desktop-background, ubuntu-tweak

I was previously using ubuntu version 12.10 and I recently upgraded to version 13.04.  Everything was working fine until I updated. Immediately after the update, my wallpaper cannot seen on screen again. Also when I use darker themes such as dorian themes, my desktop freezes. I tried all the suggested helps and answers such as dconf editor but there is no way forward.

Searching the web for answers reveals that this appears to be a general problem. I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

> #### [Download Ubuntu Tweak 0.8.4, Now Compatible With Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/download-ubuntu-tweak-084-now.html)

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade -y # it will upgrade the ubuntu tweak which is already installed
 OR
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak -y
```

[image]

Try it, I hope this will fix your issue